# Which person is Burani named after?

Tags: food, names

In [this](https://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/burani-rarely-bulani-generic-term-for-a-category-of-iranian-dishes-now-usually-prepared-with-yogurt-and-cooked-vegeta) article I found two persons as whom Burani (a Middle Eastern dish) is named after:

> According to Naḵjavānī (p. 145), the term būrānī is derived from the name of Būrān, daughter of Ḥasan b. Sahl and wife of the caliph al-Maʾmūn, who is supposed to have created this dish. The author of the Farhang-e Nafīsī (Nafīsī, I, p. 657), however, suggests the name of the Sasanian queen Būrāndoḵt (r. 630-31) as the origin of the term.

Which of these two persons is the namesake of Burani (and possibly its inventor(s))?